# clr sqlserver.exe.config encryption

Tags: sql-server-2008, clr

In general .net you can encrypt data in .config files to provide a sliver of protection to the content inside them. I need to put a username / password into the sqlserver.config.exe file to enable some CLR to connect to a remote resource.

Can you encrypt the sqlserver.exe.config file or sections of the config file in the same way you can .Net? If you can is there a best practice / do you have a recommendation for doing it. Besides the maintenance issue is there anything else I should worry about?